# What is the difference between chloride shift and Bohr shift?

Tags: human-biology

Does anyone know the difference between chloride shift and Bohr shift?

Is it that Bohr shift happens in respiring tissues when CO2 concentration is low, and that Chloride shift happens in the blood as a buffer?

Sorry for asking such a trivial question and thank you in advance. And sorry for any wrong tags or title (new to the community and is seeking to improve)